# invalid JWT when try to connect into GOOGLE OAUth2 througth Service Account (native Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, access-token, service-accounts

When trying to get a token the api returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
```

My code is as follows, I would like to know in what steps I am mistaken.

```html
 
I have a similar error: Invalid JWT Signature.

{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
My code is as follows, I would like to know in what steps I am mistaken.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-latest-all-min.js"></script>
   <!-- Including CryptoJS required libraries -->
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
    <script>
     function createJwt()
    {
      var header = {"alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT"};
   
      var payload = {
          "iss": '*****************.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
          "scope": 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
          "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
          "exp": ~~(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + (30 * 60),
          "iat": ~~(new Date().getTime() / 1000 - 60)
      };
  
      var secret = "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";
      
      var stringifiedHeader = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(header));
      var encodedHeader = base64url(stringifiedHeader);
      
      var stringifiedData = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
      var encodedData = base64url(stringifiedData);
      
      var signature = encodedHeader + "." + encodedData;
      signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signature, secret);
      signature = base64url(signature);
      $('#result').html(encodedHeader + "." + encodedData + "." + signature + "\n")
        var postData = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=" + encodedHeader + "." + encodedData + "." + signature;
      send(postData);
   };
   
   function base64url(source) 
   {
    // Encode in classical base64
    encodedSource = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(source);
    
    // Remove padding equal characters
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/=+$/, '');
    
    // Replace characters according to base64url specifications
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\+/g, '-');
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\//g, '_');
    
    return encodedSource;
  }
  
  function send(postData)
  {
   var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
   var method = "POST";
   var postData = postData;
    var async = true;
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   request.onload = function ()
   {
    var status = request.status;
    var data = request.responseText;
   }

   request.open(method, url, async);
   request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

   request.send(postData);

   $('#resultSend').val("Se ha enviado");

  }
   
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>BigQuery + JavaScript Example</h2>
 <input id="decode">
 <button id="transform" onclick="createJwt();">Decode</button>
 <br><br><br>
 <div style="widht: 400px; height: 400px; border-width: 1px; border-color: lightgrey; border-style: solid; margin-bottom: 10px;"><label id="result"></label></div>
  <div id="result_box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have reviewed several comments but nothing works. Do you have a solution or some example for native javascript?